# Not display Images at vercel

Tags: html, reactjs, vercel

I'm new using Vercel and I'm doing a school project, I've to upload to vercel my project but I have the error where my images don't show, I looked into a lot of solved questions over here but I don't have luck solving my problem.
I leave part of the code for an example with one image and the path that I believed that is correct, also the link of my project https://lalodex.vercel.app/

[image]

I tried the "/public/static/images/" path
Also I can't define the image at the beginning of the code, because I've a lot of images